# No puedo abrir un PDF desde Cordova

Tags: javascript, phonegap, apache-cordova

Estoy en un entorno de `PhoneGap`con `Cordova` para una app en `Android`.
Tengo una `URL` de un pdf , es decir:

> www.estaeslaurl/archivos/miarchivo.pdf

Ahora necesito mostrar ese `miarchivo.pdf` en el dispositivo, estoy haciendo:

```
let urlPdf = 'http://estaeslaurl/archivos/miarchivo.pdf';
            try {
                window.open(urlPdf, '_blank', '_system', 'location=yes', 'hardwareback=yes');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("ERROR", e);
            }
```

En un dispositivo real no me funciona, tampoco me sale ningún error.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Has intentado con este modulo para abrir pdf? https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Comment: No, no lo conocia, gracias

Comment: Pero no sé como se usa :/

Comment: Ahi esta la documentación para integrarlo con phonegap, [sigue estos pasos](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer#installation) :D